# How to connect to a unknown WPA-WPA2 network with ManagedWifi in C#

Tags: c#, wifi

I want to connect my network with AES encryption and WPA2 security. But when I delete the network and try to re-connect with my program I fail. What am I missing ?

```
WlanClient client = new WlanClient();

foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
{

    Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);    
    string ssid = GetStringForSSID(networks[0].dot11Ssid);
    byte[] ssidBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ssid);
    string ssidHex = BitConverter.ToString(ssidBytes);
    ssidHex = ssidHex.Replace("-", "");      
    string profileName = GetStringForSSID(networks[0].dot11Ssid);
    string mac = ssidHex;
    string key = "**PASSWORD**";
    string profile = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><WLANProfile   xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\"><name>{0}</name>   <SSIDConfig><SSID><hex>{1}</hex><name>{0}</name></SSID></SSIDConfig>  <connectionType>ESS</connectionType><MSM><security><authEncryption><authentication>open</authentication><encryption>WEP</encryption><useOneX>false</useOneX></authEncryption><sharedKey><keyType>networkKey</keyType><protected>false</protected><keyMaterial>{2}</keyMaterial></sharedKey><keyIndex>0</keyIndex></security></MSM></WLANProfile>",
    profileName, mac, key);
    wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profile, true);
    wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileName);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that you

> [...] want to connect my network with AES encryption and WPA2 security.

Anyway, looking at your profile, you are configuring the device for WEP

```
<security>
  <authEncryption>
    <authentication>open</authentication>
    <encryption>WEP</encryption> <!-- see here -->
    <useOneX>false</useOneX>
  </authEncryption>
  <sharedKey>
    <keyType>networkKey</keyType>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <keyMaterial>**PASSWORD**</keyMaterial>
  </sharedKey>
  <keyIndex>0</keyIndex>
</security>
```

I have been successful at establishing a WPA2 (PSK) connection with the following configuration

```
<security>
    <authEncryption>
        <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
        <encryption>AES</encryption>
        <useOneX>false</useOneX>
    </authEncryption>
    <sharedKey>
        <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <keyMaterial>**PASSWORD**</keyMaterial>
    </sharedKey>
</security>
```